# Windows command line argument parsing

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I am making a math expression parser in C++ and ran into an issue. When I call the program using certain operators, (for example `math 2^4`) Windows parses the caret as a special character and the program does not read it. I can escape it using backslash, but I cannot seem to escape a forward slash.

If I run `math "1(4 / 2)"`, the program only reads up to the `4`. If I run `math "1(4 \/ 2)"` however, it reads the entire expression.

My question: Can I either disable this parsing in windows or in my compiler? (I read that the parsing is actually handled by the program). I am using G++ 4.8.1. I can post code if its needed.

EDIT: Added some more examples

It does spit out an error if it sees a character not usable for math, like the backslash. I have not gotten that error while testing this.

Call: `math "1(2 + 3 - 4 / 5 * 6 % 7 ^ 8 % 9 | 10 ? 11)"` Result: `NUMBER_1 OPEN_BRACE NUMBER_2 NUMBER_3 NUMBER_5 NUMBER_9`

Call: `math "1(2 + 3 - 4 \/ 5 \* 6 \% 7 ^ 8 & 9 \| 10 ? 11)"` Result: `NUMBER_1 OPEN_BRACE NUMBER_2 NUMBER_3 DIV NUMBER_5 BAND NUMBER_9`

Comment: post a minimal example.

Comment: A minimal example of the issue? I did in the question. Wouldn't hurt to add some more tho

Comment: I suggest compiling the actual code in a DLL file, then writing a nice .exe wrapper calling it.

Comment: What your program does is not important. Just let us see the parsed `args` it's getting.

Comment: Even so much as changing which characters I escape changes which ones it sees

Comment: Rather than displaying the results _after_ your parsing, please show the contents of the command line as received when the program starts i.e. `GetCommandLine()`.

Comment: The `echo` command was invented to show what arguments a program receives. It's not quite that in Windows, because it's an internal command. Still, just try it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'd still rather see the `GetCommandLine()` collected directly from the program. `echo` has its own quirks, for example `echo a % b % c` will display `a % b % c` when run at the cmd prompt, but `a  c` when run from a batch file. In fact, I am not sure that the OP has all the quotes he posted in the actual command line, which is one thing that dumping the `GetCommandLine()` string could verify.

Comment: Dumping the command line before parsing results in exactly what is passed, without quotes.

Comment: @dxiv: The difference you see between interactive and batch is a good reason to try `echo`. It shows you what you'd get. Percent signs get special treatment in a batch file, i.e. `echo` there just tells you what it receives, as always; the behavior that's changed is not of `echo`.

Comment: @TickTock `Dumping the command line before parsing results in exactly what is passed, without quotes.` I asked about `GetCommandLine()` which returns the complete command line as entered, including quotes. If what you see has the quotes removed, then that's been already parsed and tokenized into individual arguments (at least once), perhaps by CommandLineToArgvW, or perhaps by whatever C runtime library you are using - which btw you did not indicate.

Comment: I do not know what runtime library I am using. I am compiling with gnu g++. I also do not know if `GetCommandLine()` is accessible through my program. I'll look around somewhere else then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` is an escape character in the `cmd.exe` command interpreter.

```
C:\> echo 2^5
25

C:\> echo 2^^5
2^5

C:\> echo "2^5"
"2^5"

C:\> _
```

As with the C and C++ escape character `\`, a caret at the end of a line gives a line continuation:

```
C:\> echo 2^
More? ^5
2^5

C:\> _
```

The command interpreter's behavior is not an intrinsic feature of Windows. It's not even a common Windows convention. Indeed, it's not there in Powershell:

```
C:\> powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\> echo 2^5
2^5
PS C:\> _
```

And as this establishes, as it turns out the effect you saw has **nothing to do with C++**, or even Windows, but is just a peculiarity of a particular command intepreter, namely `cmd.exe`.